# How to write video to a json file using python

Tags: python, json, video

Is there a way to write a video to a .json file? I need to download specific videos from YouTube with their categories and hashtags and write it all to a .json file as following: video: category and hashtags.

I thought about using pytube for downloading videos fron YouTube, but not sure whether it can be written to a .json file.

I expect it to be a pair: video: its category and hashtags. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Saving a video and saving the video's metadata are very different things. Your question is unclear - and too broad for SO, also.

Comment: Of course it's possible. We won't do all the work for you, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a format for text, not media. You could use requests for scraping information about the video. For example:

```
import requests
yt_vid = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IXQ6f6eMxQ').text
```

Then parse that string to try and find the relevant information, category, tags, etc.